# Cordova passbook from restful response

Tags: java, ios, angularjs, cordova, passbook

I am building a cordova application using the cordova-plugin-passbook plugin, which can be seen here: https://github.com/passslot/cordova-plugin-passbook.

I am trying to consume a pkpass from our java server that is returning the file as expected if we directly hit our service from a browser, but the problem is that we need to use an auth token and go through our oAuth server first. So I must request the pass via ajax in my front end using Angular.

The data I get back is an octet-stream and somehow I need to parse it and get it to work with the plugin above. The plugin is configured to look for a url ending in ".pkpass", I am wondering if it can be configured to look for the parsed data instead of a url.

Can anyone see in the src of the plugin if there is a possible way to do that? I am not very familiar with objective c, but just trying to think of options.

Thanks

Comment: When to say "consume a pass", I assume you mean present it to the user to add to their Wallet?

Comment: Yes @tomasmcguinness that is correct.  That plugin seems to be expecting a URL and i'm wondering if it's possible to have the plugin expect the data rather than the url to the data.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you save to disk and pass a URL that points to the local file system? I'm not very familiar with Cordovo, so that might be a useless suggestion.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness that is possibly possible, haha.  I will try to research it some, thanks.

Comment: Thank you @tomasmcguinness, I got it working thanks to your suggestion.

Comment: No problem. Glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

Using cordova fileTransfer plugin, I got this working:

```
fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry) {
        Passbook.downloadPass(fileURL);
    },
    function(error) {
        alert('Error retrieving pass, please try again in a little while.');
    },
    true,
    {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + LS.get( 'user_token' )
        }
    }
);
```